# How to rename all files which end with ".BAK"

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, batch-rename

I have a windows file system where a hiccup in our backup software renamed hundreds of files.

The change looks like this:
"ABC.PDF" -> "ABC.PDF.BAK"

This happened to some, but not all files in a directory.

I would like to rename such files to their old name, but the script should output or ignore cases where this is not possible, because a "ABC.PDF" already exists.

I am not familiar at all with batch scripts, but powershell is available too.

Comment: What do you want to do when its not possible?

Comment: @soandos Ignore the file or ideally report them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in powershell:

```
$files = dir *.BAK
foreach($file in $files) {
    Rename-Item $file $file.BaseName -ErrorAction Ignore
}
```

There will only be an error if those files no longer exist, or if you are trying to overwrite a file.

If you want to see what it will do first, add the -WhatIf flag.

Comment: I will try it in a moment, thank you very much

Comment: @ChristianSauer just as an aside, in your title you have .BAK, but in you question you have .BAL. Can you make it consistant?

Comment: Worked like a charm and I got the chance to learn more about PowerShell, thank you.

Comment: @ChristianSauer No problem. As a rule, these types of "simple" operations on files are very easy in powershell, and if you are doing something that is going to be hard to undo, just add the `-WhatIf` flag to the end of any command to see what would happen (as opposed to actually doing it). Use `-ErrorAction Continue` to report them (forgot that part until now, sorry)